How to include images when converting Markdown to RTF using Pandoc?
Title: How to Include Images When Converting Markdown to RTF Using Pandoc?
I'm working on a script that converts Markdown to RTF format using Pandoc, followed by textutil for the final conversion to RTF. My challenge is that images from the Markdown file are not appearing in the RTF output.
Here's the relevant part of my index.ts script:
// ... [previous code]
await execAsync(`${pandocPath} -f markdown-smart -t html -H ${cssHtmlPath} ${tempMarkdownPath} -o ${tempHtmlPath}`);
await execAsync(`textutil -inputencoding utf-8 -format html -convert rtf ${tempHtmlPath} -output ${tempRtfPath}`);
// ... [following code]

And here's an example of the Markdown with an image:
![Random Image](https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg)

The image appears as expected in the HTML output, but not in the final RTF file. I found out that textutil may not support embedding images during HTML to RTF conversion.
I'm looking for suggestions on alternative tools or methods that could resolve this issue, ideally without significant changes to my current workflow.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can offer advice on how to include images in RTF output?
Thank you for your assistance!

Additional Context:
I examined both the HTML and RTF files, and the problem lies in the RTF file not having the images attached. I'm seeking an alternative to textutil on macOS.
What I Want to Achieve:
I want to convert Markdown text into visually styled, formatted text and copy it to my clipboard using the macOS Raycast extension. This allows me to write an email in Markdown, run the script, and get the properly formatted text ready to send.
Here is my Raycast extension, which includes a screencast demonstrating what I want to achieve.
Here is a screencast for what I want to achieve in general:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yazanzaid00/raycast-extensions/ext/markdown-to-rich-text/extensions/markdown-to-rich-text/media/markdown-to-rich-text.gif

Out of sheer curiosity, may I ask why you're converting anything to RTF? It's curious, because arguably it's far easier to display styled HTML (and Markdown...) than RTF.

I want to convert markdown text into visually styled, formatted text and copy it to my clipboard using the macOS Raycast extension. This allows me to write an email in markdown, run the script, and get the properly formatted text ready to send.
Here is my Raycast extension, which includes a screencast demonstrating what I want to achieve.

…but email is HTML, not RTF

You're correct about that*, but it's not directly relevant to my question. Does textutil support embedding images into formatted, styled text? Assuming I have an HTML file, how can I utilize textutil to copy both the images and the styled, formatted text from it? Alternatively, do you have suggestions for other tools on macOS that could accomplish this?

Edit: Actually, I need to do more research on that. All of the articles that are trying to tackle a simpler script for what I am trying to achieve are converting to RTF using textutil. I need to do more research so I can answer you.


@CSEE from man textutil: fmt is one of:  txt, html, rtf, rtfd etc. (rtfd being text wit images) But yes, perhaps HTML is a better fit..?
